# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor produces unreachable code

Tags: java, eclipse

In my eclipse plugin I use a `ScheduledExecutorService` for a repeating task. However this seems to lead to some unreachable code within the scheduled task because I can set a breakpoint in eclipse up to a certain line and it will be reached in the debugger but when I set it one line further it is not reached... Just nothing happens then, no exception just nothing.

When I try to overstep this respective line I land somewhere in the sources of the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and my stack shows this:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask<V>(FutureTask<V>).run() line: not available [local variables unavailable]
```

Whats going on here?

Comment: Can you try with the sample code given in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: Looks to be like the classes are not getting compiled.Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851215/java-local-variable-unavailable

Comment: The sample code can be debugged without problems...

Comment: can u try cleaning the workspace and building it again?

Comment: It stays the same... The sample still has no problems but my plugin still can't be debugged

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem was that there was actually an exception being thrown but it seems like the `ScheduledExecutorService` swallows it without telling anything about it...

I foud this out by surrounding my code in the run-method with a generic try-catch-block like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        // Code
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```